# access read memo field

Tags: regex, ms-access

I have an access database that has a table with a memo field. Fields have been inserted in this format.

Apr 02 - some text
Feb 20 - some text

I would like to reverse the order of the inserts so the above would be:

Feb 20 - some text
Apr 02 - some text

I am thinking of reading line by line using regular expressions, anyone has a better path to achieve that

Comment: Are *"Apr 02 ..."* and *"Feb 20 ..."* values from 2 different rows, is that one row whose memo field contains 2 lines?

Comment: Yes it would be one row. One after the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your memo field contains 2 lines of text and you want to reverse their order.  You can do that with a simple VBA procedure, which doesn't need a regular expression.

Here is a sample Immediate window session which demonstrates techniques you can use in a VBA procedure.

```vb
MyText = "Apr 02 - some text" & vbcrlf & "Feb 20 - some text"
? MyText
Apr 02 - some text
Feb 20 - some text
? Split(MyText, vbcrlf)(1)
Feb 20 - some text
? Split(MyText, vbcrlf)(0)
Apr 02 - some text
```

If the memo field can include more than two lines of text, you can load an array with the results from `Split()` and then loop through the array in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks for the Split function, I somehow got it to work apart for the last part of reversing it.

Comment: `For x = UBound(myArray) To LBound(myArray) Step -1`